# My VS Code doesn't respect PEP8 line limit on auto formatting

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pep8, autoformatting, autoformat

I already enabled autopep8 extension and It shows rendering on bottom of my VS Code when I save the file, but It doesn't respect the line wrap in PEP8 not matter how big It is. How can I enable word wrap?

Here's my settings.json:

```
{
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,

    "[python]": {
        "editor.rulers": [90]
    },
}
```

Code example:

```py
translated_msg = self.string_parser.receive_a_string_with_or_without_tokens_and_return_it_with_the_proper_values(final_msg)
```

Sorry the long name method, It's not my fault

Shouldn't be at least this?

```py
translated_msg = self.string_parser.receive_a_string_with_or_without_tokens_and_return_it_with_the_proper_values(
    final_msg
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things. One, your settings are set to use `yapf`, not `autopep8` but your question mentions the latter. So are you using `yapf` or `autopep8`?

Two, you can specify the line length either via a configuration file or a command-line flag through [`"python.formatting.autopep8Args"`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatterspecific-settings). See the [`autopep8` docs](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8) on how to specify the line length.